# PHP, Imagick - Наложение двух изображений (merge two images with transparent)

Tags: php, изображения, imagick, merge

Есть два графических файла. Первый файл – фоновый рисунок в формате JPG
Второй файл – PNG с фигурой в центре залитой белым цветом, с черной рамкой по контуру. Основной фон PNG файла прозрачный.

Как объединить два файла с сохранением прозрачности? Фон из первого файла нужно поместить внутри фигуры на втором файле.

[image: img]